# OS doesn't recognize mounted CF card format

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to read and xfer files to a CF card used in a aircraft glass cockpit graphics server.  Windows nor Ubuntu recognize the format.  The FTP command to format the card is "quote site format /CFA".  Anyone know what format this is so I can mount the card for transfers?  FTP transfers fail when doing updates so I'm trying to make a work around.

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified the CF card is in working condition? The failure to make FTP transfers to it and the failures to access it in Windows and Ubuntu might have a common root cause: a failing CF card. I've seen SD cards and USB sticks become read-only when their internal controller detects a severe enough flash memory failure: a CF card might do likewise. If the card does not support SMART or similar diagnostic technology, becoming read-only might be the only way the CF card can tell "I'm faulty" while still allowing attempts to recover any data on the card.